# Ruby on Rails 5 : I'm getting a hash instead of an array when submiting a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

i have a form with several check boxes, where checkboxes are categories of products .

A product can be in one or many categories, and a category can have one or many products.

I'm using a has_many :through association in ruby on rails 5

when i submit a form with these check_boxes :

```
 <div class="field">
  <h5>Category</h5>
  <% Category.all.each do |c| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "product[category_ids][] ", c.id, product.category_ids.include?(c.id) %>
      <%= c.name %> <br/>
  <% end %>
```

this is what get passed as parameters :

```
"product"=>{"name"=>"Pencil", "category_ids"=>[{" "=>"1"}, {" "=>"2"}]}
```

but what i really need is something like this:

```
 "product"=>{"name"=>"Pencil", "category_ids"=>["1", "2"]}
```

i need an array not an array of hashes .

How could i get that array?.

this is what i mostly have in my product controller:

```
def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
  def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit!
  end
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: your code looks fine .. try removing that extra space `"product[category_ids][] "` after []

Comment: THANKS!!! that solved the problem. thank you , How can i reward you in stackoverflow for your answer ?

Comment: cool .. i'll add this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing that extra space on your rails' form's checkbox syntax `check_box_tag`

Update "product[category_ids][] " without the extra space to "product[category_ids][]"

```
<%= check_box_tag "product[category_ids][]", c.id, product.category_ids.include?(c.id) %>
```